# Selenium - Finding xpath by text (td / tr)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a large HTML table of emails, i'm trying to find the name of a specific email and then select a button within this element. I can easily find the table body via XPATH with:

```
//*[@id="reportList"]/tbody
```

Then within this table there are multiple rows (tr), is it possible to search for text within all table rows?

The closest i've gotten is:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="reportList"]/tbody[contains(text(), "example text")]')
```

Unfortunately this can't locate the element.

[image: html code]

I am aware I can simply copy the XPATH for the specific tr to locate, however for automation purposes i'm trying to pass a string and then search all tr's for my specific text.

Comment: Update the question with text and formatted relevant _HTML_ of the `<tr>` nodes.

Comment: add html in text format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know table has `tr` and `td`, and probably you need `td`. So the xPath could be like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='reportList']/tbody//td[contains(text(), 'example text')]")
```

where `...tbody//td...` means that it will search in all subnodes `td` of `tbody`. So `td` should not be a direct child of `tbody`

PS I would also add `wait` method to make sure that element is present:

```
# will wait up to 10 seconds until element will be present on the page
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='reportList']/tbody//td[contains(text(), 'example text')]"))
    )
```

Note: you have to do some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 3):

Three options to get your xpath:

```
XPATH= //*[@id='reportList']//*[contains(text(), 'example text')]
```

If your text is with tr:

```
XPATH= //*[@id='reportList']/tbody//tr[contains(text(), 'example text')]
```

If your text with td:

```
XPATH= //*[@id='reportList']/tbody//tr//td[contains(text(), 'example text')]
```

Comment: option 2 is not working well since the `tr` does not have text directly

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to python selenium. I am able to print the text in `td` using this line

```
XPATH= //*[@id='reportList']//*[contains(text(), 'example text')]
```

In my case, I want to loop through rows and click the link in the first column(`td`) of the rows(`tr`) which has the text 'CREATED' in the 3rd column(`td`).